# How to make a optional group, but if the group exists most match with my regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, option-type, regex-group, optional-values

I have this JS regex:

```
var re = /(\w\w\d-{1})?\w\w-{1}\w-{1}?/;
```

For file name, and the first group must be optional:

Complete name example. Example:

```
qq8-qq-q-anything => OK
```

Without first group:

```
qq-q-anything => OK
```

But if I put anything, still worked:

anything-qq-q-anything => OK

I want the first group to be optinal, but if the file name has the first group it must match with my regex word wor digit.

Comment: Do you want to allow numbers at beginning?

Comment: No, I want to be two words and one number

Comment: Then `\w` shorthand means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` that you don't need. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify that the string should "start with" your regex, so only add `^` to specify the start point.

```js
const re = /^(\w\w\d-{1})?\w\w-{1}\w-{1}?/;

const strs = ['qq8-qq-q-anything', 'qq-q-anything', 'anything-qq-q-anything'];


const result = strs.map(str => re.test(str));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

`\w` matches both digits and letters. It includes `_` character too. You should explicitly use a character class for letters and anchor your regex with circumflex `^` to assert start of input string. You don't need to have `{1}` quantifier either since a preceding pattern is only checked once unless defined otherwise. You may need `i` (case-insensitive) flag too:

```
var re = /^(?:[a-z]{2}\d-)?[a-z]{2}-[a-z]-/i;
```

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/GZw8N7/1)**